# webapi ignore route : domain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

i need to add the following file to a webapi site

```
apple-app-site-association
.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

i need to ignore the route so that i can access the file via url.

```
http://domain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

http://domain/apple-app-site-association
```

please suggest what to add to `RegisterRoutes`, so that i can see the json for these 2 files directly in browser.

Comment: Use config.Routes.IgnoreRoute extension method before your routes in RegisterRoutes method.

Comment: Tried that. All my combinations did not work. Please suggest exact line of code for above 2 if possible